# How do I know how many arguments explode created

Tags: php, arguments, explode

Using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), How can I check how many arguments explode created? Is there function which check this or do I have to primary check how many times a character I chose to split on appears in string?

Comment: Would a simple count(); not work?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php function or http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php.

Comment: Explode returns an array, you can count() the elements inside, if this is your question

Answer (score 1):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) return an array, the number of array elements can be returned with [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

`$number = count(explode([a, b, c])); // 3`

Answer (score 0):

Return array after explode, use count() will do.

```
$str = 'Apple, Mango, Orange, Banana';
$exp = explode(',',$str);
echo count($exp);
```